# How to jmock Final class

Tags: junit

I was trying to mock final class(AnyFinalClass.java) in junit using JDave in eclipse.

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Mockery mockery = new Mockery() {{
        setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    }};

    AnyFinalClass any = mockery.mock(AnyFinalClass.class);
}
```

I am trying to use jdave-unfinalizer-1.1.jar as javaagent but didnt had any success. I tried multiple things but getting following exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class AnyFinalClass
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)

Can someone who has already tried jdave unfinalizer give me exact step how to make it work on eclipse.

I set following in eclipse.ini file but got the problem
-Xbootclasspath/a:lC:\WS\JunitTesting\jars\asm-3.0.jar
-javaagent:C:\WS\JunitTesting\jars\jdave-unfinalizer-1.1.jar

While running executing the junit, I gave vm argument as 
javaagent:C:\WS\JunitTesting\jars\jdave-unfinalizer-1.1.jar

I am not sure what will be the code. jdave is not having the code and its site is pointing to some other site which is not working. Please correct my code or provide your same working code.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try tu put -javaagent:YOUR_PATH\jdave-unfinalizer-1.1.jar as VM argument in your test run configuration instead of using "bootclasspath" in eclipse.ini

Answer (score 2):

from Enhancer.java line 446:

```
if (TypeUtils.isFinal(sc.getModifiers()))
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot subclass final class " + sc);
```

I have not worked with JDave but with another mocking frameworks and the only one that allows to mock a final class was [powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/)
Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575641/powermock-mockito-and-mocking-final-class-from-the-reflection-api)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get unfinalizer running  you have to put `-javaagent:path_to_unfinalizer/jdave-unfinalizer-1.1.jar` in the VM arguments of the run configuration of the test.

I also had to include several dependencies of jdave-unfinalizer in the classpath of the project from which the tests ar being launched. These are, taken from the maven definitions of jdave:

```
jdave-core 1.1
cglib-nodep 2.1_3
objenesis 1.0
asm 3.0
asm-commons 3.0
asm-tree 3.0
```